# How HtmlHelper know data is on the ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I was watching a tutorial about `HtmlHelper` for DropDown https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79aYSOcmpV8

Around min 8, he is reading the db to replace some hardcode values.

> To pass list of Departments from the controller, store them in "ViewBag"

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Connect to the database
    SampleDBContext db = new SampleDBContext();
    // Retrieve departments, and build SelectList
    ViewBag.Departments = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name");

    return View();
}
```

Last step.

> Now in the "Index" view, access Departments list from "ViewBag"

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", "Select Department")
```

I dont see anything like strong type model on the view.

### So how the `Helper` know `Departments` refers to a value in the ViewBag?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that that is an awful solution, `ViewBag` properties are added to `ViewData` (along with any model passed to the view) and the `HtmlHelper` methods search `ViewData` - in this case finding a matching key for `Departments`

Comment: That make sense, didnt know the model was passed on the `ViewBag`. What aproach would you use? The tutorial was made in the 2013 so maybe is outdated. My guess is create the `Deparment` model and use a strong type view.

Comment: The model is not passed as `ViewBag` - is added to `ViewData`. Using a view model with properties for the selected department and the department list is always the best approach, as is using the strongly typed helpers - so in the view its (say) `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.DepartmentList, "Select Department")`

Comment: I see now. To me ViewBag and ViewData were the same, execpt diferent syntaxis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a value to `ViewBag`, it is also added to the `ViewData` property of `ViewContext` when the view is generated. The `DropDownList()` overload that your using in equivalent to passing a `null` SelectList in

```
@Html.DropDownList("Departments", null, "Select Department")
```

in which case, internally, the helper searches the `ViewData` property to find a matching key which is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which `"Departments"` is). You can see the relevant code in the `private static MvcHtmlString SelectInternal()` method of the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs)

```
// If we got a null selectList, try to use ViewData to get the list of items.
if (selectList == null)
{
    selectList = htmlHelper.GetSelectData(name);
    ....
}
```

Note that the example in the tutorial is a poor approach, using 'magic' strings and requiring you to access the value in the POST method using `Request.Form["Departments"]`. A far better approach is to use a view model and strongly bind to your view model, for example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and the GET method would be

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel
    {
        DepartmentList = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Id", "Name");
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model MyViewModel
....
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.DepartmentList, "Select Department")
```

and post the form back to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
```